# Modern SharePoint 2019 fail to delete files in document folder

Tags: document-library, error, document, modern-experience, 2019

I encounter an error when I attempt to delete any file (not locked or checked out) when I am using Modern view.
The error message is appears on the too right hand corner with the message:

> The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070032).

I do not encounter this error when I switch to Classic SharePoint and when I attempt to delete the same file. The file can only be deleted in Classic View.

When I selected the file I want to delete and clicked delete, two errors appear.

First is a 500 Internal server error with the message "ClientServiceException. The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be usee to access the resource 'Recycle'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use the corrext HTTP method to invoke the resource."

The other error is a 403 forbidden on access WsaUpload.ashx. Error message is simply Forbidden. No further. No further details.

Comment: Not enough info to help. You should provide browser console logs (F12 -> Console) as well as ULS logs when you're attempting to delete the file.

Comment: When I selected the file I want to delete and clicked delete, two errors appear. First is a 500 Internal server error with the message "ClientServiceException. The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be usee to access the resource 'Recycle'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use the corrext HTTP method to invoke the resource."   The other error is a 403 forbidden on access WsaUpload.ashx. Error message is simply Forbidden. No further. No further details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Recycle bin is enabled on your web application;
[check this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-sharepoint-recycle-bin-settings-427bf749-cfb4-4b5a-80aa-3bd2b24ef4f0)

Comment: We do not wish to use the recycle bin. Is this a must for modern view?

Comment: This Exception HRESULT:0x80070032 usually come from a permission issue or recycle bin issue

Comment: Its a recycle bin issue. Once I enable recycle bin the error goes away. However, we wish to disable the recycle bin.

Comment: is it working fine with you now?

Comment: Turning it on removes the error. But it does not solve the issue. We wish to disable recycle bin while using in modern view.